# SimpleCursorAdapter приложение падает при выводе данных

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. После заполнения данными полей ввода и нажатии на кнопку, приложение падает. Все дело в методе, который читает данные из таблицы и заполняет список ListView с помощью SimpleCursorAdapter. Не могу понять, в чем дело. Подскажите. В начале показываю сам метод, потом файлы для полной картины. Спасибо.

***метод, в котором проблема (скорее всего)***

```
public void funRead(ListView listView) {
  db = abcDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

  String[] columns = {AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_ID, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_EN, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_RU};
  cursor = db.query(AbcDbContract.TableWords.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

  int[] items = {R.id.textViewItem1, R.id.textViewItem2, R.id.textViewItem3};

  simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.item, cursor, columns, items, 0);

  listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

  cursor.close();
  db.close();
 }
```

Теперь файлы для полной картины.
***item.xml*** им заполняется ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#5cb85c"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewItem1"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#428bca"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewItem2"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#d9534f"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewItem3"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="#428bca"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="en"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#f9f9f9"
            android:background="#428bca"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp" />
        <EditText
            android:text=""
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textColor="#428bca"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#f9f9f9"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="#d9534f"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="ru"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#f9f9f9"
            android:background="#d9534f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp" />
        <EditText
            android:text=""
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textColor="#d9534f"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#f9f9f9"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text="OK"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#f9f9f9"
            android:background="#5cb85c"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:onClick="button1Click"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

***AbcDbContract.java*** класс-контракт определяющий схему БД

```
package ru.site.a1;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

//класс контракт определяющий схему БД
public final class AbcDbContract {

 //закрытый конструктор не допускает создание объектов
 private AbcDbContract() {}

 //имя БД
 public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "abc.db";

 //номер версии БД
 public static final int DATA_BASE_VERSION = 1;

 //класс определяет имя таблицы и имена столбцов
 public static abstract class TableWords implements BaseColumns {
  //имя таблицы
  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_words";
  //имена столбцов
  public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
  public static final String COLUMN_NAME_EN = "en";
  public static final String COLUMN_NAME_RU = "ru";
 }

 //SQL-запрос : создание или открытие таблицы
 public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_WORDS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableWords.TABLE_NAME + " (" + TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_EN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_RU + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

 //SQL-запрос : удаление таблицы
 public static final String SQL_DELETE_TABLE_WORDS = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableWords.TABLE_NAME;
}
```

***AbcDbHelper.java***

```
package ru.site.a1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class AbcDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 public AbcDbHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, AbcDbContract.DATA_BASE_NAME, null, AbcDbContract.DATA_BASE_VERSION);
 }

 //метод вызывается при создании БД
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  db.execSQL(AbcDbContract.SQL_CREATE_TABLE_WORDS);
 }

 //метод вызывается при обновлении БД
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  db.execSQL(AbcDbContract.SQL_DELETE_TABLE_WORDS);
  onCreate(db);
 }

}
```

***AbcDb.java*** в этом классе этот метод

```
package ru.site.a1;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class AbcDb {

 private Context context;
 private AbcDbHelper abcDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase db;
 private Cursor cursor;
 private SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
 private ContentValues contentValues;

 public AbcDb(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
  abcDbHelper = new AbcDbHelper(context);
 }

 //метод : запись данных
 public void funWrite(EditText editText1, EditText editText2) {
  db = abcDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  contentValues = new ContentValues();

  //добавление в строку имя столбца и значение
  contentValues.put(AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_EN, editText1.getText().toString());
  contentValues.put(AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_RU, editText2.getText().toString());
  //вставка строки в таблицу (имя таблицы, если пустая строка, объект ContentValues)
  db.insert(AbcDbContract.TableWords.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

  db.close();
 }

 //метод : чтение данных
 public void funRead(ListView listView) {
  db = abcDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

  String[] columns = {AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_ID, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_EN, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_RU};
  cursor = db.query(AbcDbContract.TableWords.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

  int[] items = {R.id.textViewItem1, R.id.textViewItem2, R.id.textViewItem3};

  simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.item, cursor, columns, items, 0);

  listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

  cursor.close();
  db.close();
 }

}
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package ru.site.a1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private EditText editText1;
 private EditText editText2;
 private ListView listView1;

 private AbcDb abcDb;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

  abcDb = new AbcDb(this);

  //чтение данных
  abcDb.funRead(listView1);
 }

 public void button1Click(View view) {

  //проверка на пустоту поля ввода
  if(editText1.getText().toString().equals("") | editText2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Заполните поле ввода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else {
   //запись и чтение данных
   abcDb.funWrite(editText1, editText2);
   abcDb.funRead(listView1);

   //очистка поля ввода
   editText1.setText("");
   editText2.setText("");
   //установка фокуса
   editText1.requestFocus();
  }

 }
}
```

**ВЫВОД ОШИБКИ**

```
1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.site.a1, PID: 16421
android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:139)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:150)
at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:254)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2828)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1294)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1206)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1082)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:614)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3076)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2411)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1429)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1677)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1314)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7057)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:829)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:576)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: А где ошибка с которой падает?

Comment: для полной картины совсем не нужны больше половины выложенных вами файлов, но совершенно необходим стектрейс с ошибкой при падении приложения

Comment: Уважаемый  pavlofff, если бы Вам действительно было бы интересно разобраться в этой ошибке, то Вы бы создали у себя пустой проект, добавили эти файлы и запустили проект. Для этого я и выложил все файлы. Потому что, это тема фундаментальная. Я попытался разложить ее на очень простые составляющие.

Comment: @Anton вы полагаете, что кому-то кроме вас интересно копаться в ваших кодах? Вынужден вас огорчить - это никому неинтересно. Дайте стектрейс и вам быстро подскажут причину падения, дальше уж сами

Comment: Кто-то уже заминусовал ваш вопрос, так и быть подниму - но выводы сделать надо

Comment: Уважаемый pavlofff добавил ошибку при падении.